# How to run Nhibernate ICriteria query with setFetchMode(Lazy) when lazy=false defined in HBM?

Tags: nhibernate, fetch, icriteria, lazy-evaluation, hbm

I'd like to run a criteria query with lazy many-to-one associations. Those associations are set as `lazy="false"` in the HBM. It's because we use it eagerly 90% of the project.

But there are a few 'big' queries that should run as `lazy="proxy"`.

HBM:

```
<many-to-one name="DestinationElement" class="X" column="DstElemId" not-null="true" unique="false" cascade="save-update" outer-join="auto" fetch="select" lazy="false" index="IDX_Ass_DestElem">
```

Criteria setup:

```
criteria.SetFetchMode("DestinationElement", FetchMode.Lazy);
```

It works the opposite way, but not this way. It fetches eagerly.

The LOC is 20K+, and it'd be a massive refactor to do it the opposite way.

How can I force this to fetch lazily only when I want, and fetch eagerly all other times?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`lazy="false"` in the HBM cannot be overriden in a query (besides being a bad idea 99% of the time)

You'll have to change your code.

Comment: Thanks. In the meantime I realized that it couldn't be done. So, we'll change the code.

Comment: It'd be good to have this option, but as I knew, it was a design issue why we used some associations eagerly. It was because we needed the eagerly fetched property as a real object: we needed to cast but it was fetched as a parent of the real object so cast was not possible. E.g. We have a Patient that has a property Therapist that is a Person. Actually, this person is always a Doctor that is inherited from Person. So, when I fetch Person lazily, I cannot cast it to Doctor, because only the "Person-part" is available.
It was because of having wrong 'Equals' methods

Comment: So, getting Therapist lazily as Person, it cannot be cast to Doctor. But, if we set the property to fetch it eagerly, it IS a Doctor. That's why we used it that way. But when fetching multiple Patients, all the Doctors are fetched, too. In this case, it gets real slow. I know it could be joined, too, but that way query size gets 100K+ and Oracle couldn't handle it. So, this was a complex situation where az immediate quick and dirty solution was needed. But as we know, qad solutions are always hit back:D

Comment: I've written about how to solve that problem here: http://sessionfactory.blogspot.com/2010/08/hacking-lazy-loaded-inheritance.html

Comment: Very nice solution!!! I'll have to try it out:) I found UnProxy and decided to use that, but I'll give this a try. Hope it will be consistent because I found a very strange behaviour of NH cache.